# How to read variable child nodes from an xml file?

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing

I need to parse an xml config file with a variable number of nodes which in turn contain a variable number of child nodes. How do I read in all the values no matter how many VM nodes or vmClient nodes I have? I'm using C# with VS2012 for this project.
As an aside, if there's a better way to structure my data in the xml file, let me know! Here's the xml file:

```
<!--VM settings on ESX Server-->
<VM name="DE2008">
    <vmLanguage value = "de"/>
    <vmSnapshot value = "test"/>
    <vmPowerOn value = "true"/>
    <vmClients>
        <vmClient name="ITXPPRO">
            <vmClientSnapshot value="test2"/>
            <vmClientLanguage value="it"/>
        </vmClient>
        <vmClient name="JPXPPRO">
            <vmClientSnapshot value="test3"/>
            <vmClientLanguage value="jp"/>
        </vmClient>
    </vmClients>
</VM>

<VM name="FR2003">
    <vmLanguage value = "fr"/>
    <vmSnapshot value = "test"/>
    <vmPowerOn value = "true"/>
    <vmClients>
        <vmClient name="DAWIN7">
            <vmClientSnapshot value="autotc"/>
            <vmClientLanguage value="da"/>
        </vmClient>
    </vmClients>
</VM>

<!--SQL Servers used as database servers for ePO-->
<sqlServers>
    <sqlName value = "DE2008SQL"/>
    <sqlLanguage value = "de"/>
    <sqlSnapshot value = "sql"/>
</sqlServers>
```

Comment: What have you tried? Have you looked at using Linq2Xml? Also, you can't have multiple xml roots in one document.

Comment: If the structure does not change (often), I suggest you deserialize it and then just iterate "regular" objects. Check lazyberezovsky's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you to use LINQ to XML

```
var xdoc = XDocument.Load(path_to_xml);
var query = from vm in xdoc.Descendants("VM")
            select new {
               Name = (string)vm.Attribute("name"),
               Language = (string)vm.Element("vmLanguage").Attribute("value"),
               Snapshot = (string)vm.Element("vmSnapshot").Attribute("value"),
               PowerOn = (bool)vm.Element("vmPowerOn").Attribute("value"),
               Clients = from c in vm.Element("vmClients").Elements()
                         select new {
                            Name = (string)c.Attribute("name"),
                            // etc
                         }
            };
```

Also I suggest you to store values directly as element values, or in attributes, so instead of

```
Language = (string)vm.Element("vmLanguage").Attribute("value")
```

You will be able to use (also you will not get exception if some element missing)

```
Language = (string)vm.Element("vmLanguage") // if value stored in element
// or
Language = (string)vm.Attribute("vmLanguage") // if value stored in attribute
```

And prefix `vm` looks kind of weird to me. Why not simply use `language` if it's part of `vm` data? So, I'd go with following configuration:

```
<vm name="DE2008" language="de" shapshot="test" powerOn="true">
    <clients>
        <client name="ITXPPRO" snapshot="test2" language="it"/>
        <client name="ITXPPRO" snapshot="test3" language="jp"/>
    </clients>
</vm>
```

Comment: Thanks for your great answer. I'm going to do as you suggested. My apologies but I'm new to LINQ - how do I extract the node attributes from query? Do I have to convert it to a list or something? Thanks so much for your time and help.

Comment: @bearaman this query returns sequence of anonymous types. You can enumerate them in foreach, or convert to list with `var vms = query.ToList()` call. Then you will be able to get items by index `vms[0].Language`

Comment: @bearaman one more note - anonymous type here just for sample. You can create `VM` and `VMClient` classes and return instances of these classes instead of anonymous types

Comment: One last thing, when I do a foreach to loop through query, I get the results for the VM but not for the clients - it gives me a long message about Linq. I think it's because Clients returns yet another list and not a string. How can I access the list of Clients?

Answer (score 1):

your  just use something like this

```
    XDocument xDocument = XDocument.Load(yourconfigfilepath);


            var firstresult = xDocument.Descendants("VM");
foreach (var elt in result)
            {
                var childforeachNode = xDocument.Descendants("vmClient");

            }
```